# How to update a single parent table based on multiple values in the child table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to update my parent table column if my child table column has all the same values for a single ParentId.

**T1** - Parent

```
|      ParentId       |    StatusId      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**T2** - Child

```
|      ChildId        |     ParentId     |    StatusId      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          4          |       2          |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          5          |       2          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

If T2 status column has all 0's for ParentId 1 then set status in T1 to 0 else if there is a 1 status for any ParentId in T2 then set the status in T1 to 1 or do nothing.

Desired Result after update statement:

**T1** - Parent

```
|      ParentId       |    StatusId      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       0          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       1          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**T2** - Child

```
|      ChildId        |     ParentId     |    StatusId      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       1          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          4          |       2          |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          5          |       2          |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I know can perhaps do something like this using an update and maybe a while loop but I'm not quite sure how to construct it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE PT
SET PT.StatusId = CASE  
                 WHEN PT.StatusId = 1 THEN 1
                 WHEN CT.StatusId IN (0,1) THEN 1
               END 
FROM ParentTable PT JOIN ChildTable CT
ON PT.ParentID = CT.ParentId

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid while loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an [Update From Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334712/1043031)

```
Update T1
    Set StatusID = newStatusID
From
(
    Select ParentID as changedParentID
        , max(StatusID) as newStatusID
    From T2
    Group By ParentID
)x
Where T1.ParentID = x.changedParentID
And T1.StatusID <> x.newStatusID
```

Comment: This is a very simple but great solution.  Sometimes the answer to problems can be so small but you find your time looking for harder solutions when you don't need to.